# Why are programmatically set weights for Android linear layout columns not working correctly?

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

I am attempting to create a key for an above pie chart within this Linear layout. However, the weights aren't working properly, and the three columns are split up equally. Does anyone know what may be causing this? Thanks!

Layout XML:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">
        <TableRow android:gravity="center"
            android:id="@+id/tableRow"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:weightSum="4">
            <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:id="@+id/aiButton"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:src="@drawable/barchartwhite"
                android:background="#CCAF00"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:text="TP Activity"
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_gravity="center|center_vertical"
                android:textSize="40sp"
                android:background="#CCAF00"
                android:layout_weight="3"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:gravity="center_vertical" />
        </TableRow>
        <TableRow android:gravity="center"
            android:id="@+id/tableRowSub"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Percentage of Activity per TP"
                android:id="@+id/textViewSub"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="5dip">

            <com.shannonsystemsllc.ediconnect.PieChartView
                xmlns:chart="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                android:id="@+id/piechart"
                android:paddingRight="12dp"
                android:paddingLeft="12dp"
                android:layout_width="300sp"
                android:layout_height="300dp"/>
        </TableRow>

    </LinearLayout>
```

Code for creating key:

```
for (int i = 0; i < customers.size(); i++) {
                int c[] = {Color.parseColor("#FF4B66"),Color.parseColor("#00A9AC"),Color.parseColor("#70A200"),Color.parseColor("#FAB448"),Color.parseColor("#BFBFBF"),Color.GREEN,custColor,Color.CYAN,Color.BLUE};


                    TableRow.LayoutParams lp = new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
                    TableLayout.LayoutParams tl = new TableLayout.LayoutParams();

                    final float scale = getActivity().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
                    int pixels = (int) (30 * scale + 0.5f); //set pixels to dp
                    TableRow row = new TableRow(activity);
                    row.setWeightSum(9);
                    //first row
                    tl.weight = 1;
                    lp.weight = 6;
                    lp.height = pixels;
                    row.setLayoutParams(lp);
                    TextView tv1a = new TextView(getActivity());
                    tv1a.setTextSize(22);
                    tv1a.setText(customers.get(i));
                    tv1a.setLayoutParams(lp);
                    tv1a.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT | Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);

                    TextView tv1b = new TextView(getActivity());
                    tv1b.setTextSize(24);
                    Float perFloat = ((float)pieChartValues[i]/dataTotal*100);
                    remainderTotal = remainderTotal - perFloat.intValue();
                    String percentage;
                    if (perFloat.intValue() == 0)
                    {
                        percentage = ("1%");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        percentage = (perFloat.intValue() + "%");
                    }

                    lp.weight = 2;
                    tv1b.setText(percentage);
                    tv1b.setLayoutParams(lp);
                    tv1b.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT | Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);

                    lp.weight = 1;
                    ImageView tv1c = new ImageView(getActivity());
                    tv1c.setLayoutParams(lp);
                    tv1c.setBackgroundColor(c[i]);

                    row.setWeightSum(3);
                    row.addView(tv1b);
                    row.addView(tv1c);
                    row.addView(tv1a);
                    row.setId(i);
                    ll.addView(row);
                }
```

Screenshot:
[image]

Comment: How do you want them to split up?

Comment: Basically I am trying to set them to 6/9, 2/9, and 1/9 with the colored column being the smallest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the weight of the contents inside each row as follows:
 - For the percentage TextView, set the weight to 3.
 - For the ImageView, set the weight to 8.
 - For the name Textview, set the weight to 7.

This will result to the entire row to look slightly offset from the centre. Make sure all three views are set to match parent width.

Comment: Thanks, I caught that I had accidentally set weightSum twice and fixed that, but this also helped set the ratios to look proper for the columns.

Comment: Even I overlooked that, glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

Once you set weights for the views call:

```
     yourLinearLayout.invalidate()
```

Try this out and see if it works.